# What denomination of Christianity did Anne Boleyn believe in?

Tags: tudor-period

It is agreed upon by historians that Henry VIII's second wife Anne was a reformist against the Roman Catholic Church during the Tudor period. But what sect of Christianity did she favor in particular as the ruling religion in the church of England?

Comment: The title could be improved : you believe in God, Christ and so on as a Christian, you follow one of the denomination.

Answer (score 10):

[Ann Boleyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Boleyn) and her brother, [George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boleyn,_2nd_Viscount_Rochford), were executed in 1536.  It appears that her family had taken a great interest in the [early writings of Martin Luther](https://muse.jhu.edu/book/25217), some of which he [translated](https://classroom.synonym.com/anne-boleyns-religious-beliefs-12085875.html).

Though there were a number of protestant sects by 1530, [the reform movement of John Calvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Calvin#Reform_work_commences_(1536%E2%80%931538)) was not yet in existence, nor were Anglicans, Presbyterians, or most other modern denominations.  This does not necessarily make Anne Boleyn a Lutheran, for that would have required a Lutheran Church, which was lacking in England.

Comment: Earlier she had been very interested in the writings of Tyndale (later executed by Henry), which mixed religion and politics and seemed to point a way for Henry to have sovereign power over the church rather than vice versa.  https://www.theanneboleynfiles.com/anne-boleyn-william-tyndale-henry-viii/

Comment: Tyndale's thought was closer to Zwingli and the other Swiss reformers than it was to Luther's.

Comment: Tyndale was executed in Vilvoorde (now in Flemish Brabant in Belgium) by the Hapsburg Imperial and Catholic authorities, not by Henry VIII of England

Comment: Trust @Henry to know who henry had executed.